# MySQL execution time of subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

When I am executing the bellow sql query the execution time is 0.0009 seconds

```
SELECT min(step_number) as min_sn, request_id as rid  
  from request_step  
  where state = 'pending'  
  GROUP BY request_id
```

But when I am executing the next one the execution time is 0.6511 seconds

```
select rs0.*
from (SELECT min(step_number) as min_sn, request_id as rid  
  from request_step  
  where state = 'pending'  
  GROUP BY request_id  
  ) rs0
```

I can not understand why, also the number of records is 59675

Comment: You would have to look at the execution plans.  That said,  don't know why these would be different.

Comment: How many times did you run the queries? Are those numbers averages or just first try? Try adding `SQL_NO_CACHE` after `SELECT` keyword in both queries and note the times.

Comment: BTW, 0.0009 is _very_ fast by MySQL standards for 59675 rows, that too after grouping.

Comment: I execute the query multiple times and the numbers are the average. The same situation if I add SQL_NO_CACHE after select

Comment: The **first** thing you should do when trying to understand how a query execute is to look at the explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for for a comment.

The two should have the same performance *if the data does not change*.  MySQL generally saves to disk for the `GROUP BY`, so materializing the subquery is not going to have much impact on performance.

If this execute very fast (a fraction of a millisecond), then I can only imagine the following scenario:

- There is an index on `(status, request_id, step_number)`.
- Very, very few rows with `status = 'pending'`.

`status = 'pending'` then suggests that the database is changing in real time.  That, in turn, suggests that rows or the entire table is being locked.  If this is the case, the difference in performance is simply due to other things happening on the system.

I am not guaranteeing that this explains the performance difference.  It is just seems like a reasonable explanation for the wide variation in performance times.

Comment: the db it's demo and all rows are pending and none of the rows are locked. If I set the index (status, request_id, step_number) then the execution time from 0.65 goes to 0.25

Answer (score 0):

In the second version, it appears that you are executing 2 queries.

First

```
SELECT min(step_number) as min_sn, request_id as rid  
from request_step  
where state = 'pending'  
GROUP BY request_id
```

will execute and the results with be gathered.

Then,

```
select rs0.* from <results> as rs0
```

will be run against the result set from the first query. This will increase execution time due to MySQL setting up the query, gathering the results and then setting up the next query.

Incidentally, although an index will speed up the first query, there is no opportunity to create an index on the the results and so any attempt at filtering after the first query has run will have significant performance implications for any large dataset.

Comment: as you can from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56184223/how-to-get-next-step/56185059#56185059) I want to check the previous state. The final query is "select count(rs0.rid) as cnt 
from 
(SELECT min(step_number) as min_sn, request_id as rid   from request_step where state = 'pending'
GROUP BY request_id   ) rs0 
left join request_permission rp on rp.request_step_id = rs0.rid 
left join request_user ru on ru.id = rp.request_user_id 
left join request r on r.id = rs0.rid where r.state = 'pending' and ru.user_id =1" and even the count it takes almost 0.600 sec

Comment: Can you help me wiith a workarround to check the preivous state without nested select?